# Haskell pair and unpair functions

Tags: haskell, coding-style, tuples

I have the following two functions written.

```
pair :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pair [] = []
pair [x] = []
pair (x1:x2:xs) = (x1, x2) : pair xs

unpair :: [(a, a)] -> [a]
unpair [] = []
unpair ((x1, x2):xs) = x1 : x2 : unpair xs
```

Pair will take pairs of elements and make 2-tuples of them. If the list has an odd number of elements, discard the last one. Unpair is the reverse of pair.

These work, but wondering whether there is a more succinct way to write these.

Comment: It may be slightly verbose, but I'd say it wins hands down in terms of clarity compared to the answers so far.  (No offense meant to those authors.)

Comment: I think the takeaway here is that an everyOther function on lists would be useful since people do gravitate toward the zip approach. The splits package on Hackage has splitEvery which would make this style of solution more perspicuous.

Comment: Hate to say it, but to the alternatives I've seen so far: I said succinct, not obtuse. :(

Answer (score 5):

One-liners:

```
pair xs = map snd . filter fst . zip (iterate not True) $ zip xs (drop 1 xs)
unpair = concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y])
```

You could have also abbreviate your definition of `pair` a little:

```
pair (x1:x2:xs) = (x1, x2) : pair xs
pair _ = []
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not any more concise, but for the sake of clarity I'd use `splitEvery` from [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) for `pair`:

```
pair = map tuplify . filter ((>1) . length) . splitEvery 2
  where
    tuplify [x, y] = (x, y)
```

This is off the top of my head—it would be nicer to check the length of the last list only.

For `unpair` I'd use `foldr` to avoid the explicit recursion:

```
unpair = foldr (\(x, y) -> (x:) . (y:)) []
```

This is just a matter of taste.

Comment: +1 to support my ongoing campaign promoting use of the name `tuplify`.

Comment: `unpair = foldr (\\(x, y) -> ([x, y] ++)) []` is nicer imo.

Answer (score 2):

So many possibilities. How about these?

```
unpair' = concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y])
pair' xs = map snd . filter fst . zip (cycle [True, False]) $ zip xs (tail xs)
pair'' xs = [(x,y) | (True,x,y) <- zip3 (cycle [True,False]) xs (tail xs)]
```

The two versions of pair should be the same.

Edit: Regarding my comment above, one can use the split package from Hackage to write:

```
pair xs = map head . splitEvery 2 $ zip xs (tail xs)
```

which is closer to the desired

```
pair xs = everyOther $ zip xs (tail xs)
```

But, in the spirit of pointlessness, I think we should probably all agree on writing it,

```
pair = map head . splitEvery 2 . (zip <$> id <*> tail)
```

to ensure confusion.

Comment: Nice version with list comprehension. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
pair s = dropEven $ zip s (tail s)
     where dropEven s = map fst $ filter snd $ zip s (cycle [True, False])

unpair = concatMap (\(a, b) -> [a, b])
```

Though I definitely prefer your definition of `pair`.

Comment: We came up with almost identical solutions :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice use for [view patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

pair :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pair (splitAt 2 -> ([x,y],ys)) = (x,y) : pair ys
pair _ = []

unpair :: [(a,a)] -> [a]
unpair = (>>= \(x,y) -> [x,y])
```

Comment: I don't think that `pair (splitAt 2 -> ([x,y],ys)) =` is more readable than just `pair (x:y:ys) =`.

Comment: But that doesn't use view patterns... `:-)`